# How can I pick two values from the same array from json response of an API without hardcoding them using JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have the sample JSON response of a GET API that resembles as below

```
  {
    "result" : "OK",
    "List":[{
    "zid":"1",
"Sheet":
    {
      "aid":123,
      "bid":435,
      "Type":"Samsung"
    },
     "yid":{
        "cid":987
      }
    },
    {
    "zid":"2",
"Sheet":
    {
      "aid":657,
      "Type":"nokia"
    },
     "yid":{
        "cid":908
      }
    },
   {
    "zid":"3",
"Sheet":
    {
      "aid":555,
      "bid":666,
      "Type":"Samsung"
    },
     "yid":{
        "cid":999
      }
    }
    ]}
    and so on till zid is 50
```

Using Jmeter I want to extract cid and bid of the same zid. I have tried by using json extractor where I have given jsonpath expression as: $..bid,checked the check box compute concatenation, didn't give any match number and did the similar for cid($..cid) as well,when I passs these two values in another post request using ${bid} and ${cid}, I see that both of the bid and cid are being picked from two different zid arrays instead of the same zid. I don't want to hardcode it by giving match number as 1 or something as in few cases bid might be absent for some (eg:when type is nokia there is no bid)[I tried giving match number as 0 still the same problem].

And also zid value is dynamic will not be the same everytime, Is there any solution where I can extract cid and bid from same array with any extractor in Jmeter. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If neither [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) nor [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) give you what you want you can always consider using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) which allows you executing arbitrary [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code.

So you can do something like:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
```

and you will get `response` object which will be either a List in case of JSON Array or a Map in case of JSON Object. So you will be able to iterate all "zid" values and choose first/last/random/whatever and fetch the "pair" of "bid" and "cid" for particular this object.

You posted an invalid JSON hence I cannot provide the final working code, hopefully the hint makes sense.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: I have tried it with jsr223 postprocessor, i am not getting how to iterate and pick bid and cid as pair..I have edited into correct json format can you please help me out

Comment: Something like `b = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).List.findAll { zid -> zid.Sheet.bid != null }; r = b.get(new Random().nextInt(b.size())); vars.put('bid', r.Sheet.bid as String); vars.put('cid', r.yid.cid as String)` should do the trick for you. Refer extracted values as `${bid}` and `${cid}` where required.  See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information about what do these **vars** and **prev** guys mean